# Updating column based on value of specific submit button clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not too sure how i should even ask this question, but i'm going to go ahead and try and explain it as well as i can - let me know if anything i've said doesn't make sense.

I'm creating a community-based website as a personal learning project for myself and as part of the website, users will be able to join a specific 'group' - a group would be a place where users can discuss common interests etc. So far i have two groups that i've created to test with and i'm trying to assign a user to one of the groups based on which button they click.

The code below displays information about the group on the page and also the button for joining that specific group. Of course, when a user clicks to join a group, it just joins the first group, even if i click on the second displayed button since i'm getting the value from join_group since i only have one name.

I know my inputs haven't been sanitized, but that's something i'm leaving until later.

What i need to do is have some sort of foreach i think, for the `$_POST['join_group']` but not entirely sure how to go about it. Any ideas?

Displaying the groups

```
foreach ($group_info as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div>Group name: " . $value['group_name'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div>Description: " . $value['description'] . "</div>";
    echo "<div>Members: " . $value['group_size'] . "</div>";                    
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo "<input name='group_id' type='hidden' value='" . $value[0][$i] ."'>";
    echo "<button name='join_group' class='btn btn-green'>Join Group</button>";
    echo "</form>";

    $i = $i++;
}
```

Inserting the data

```
if (isset($_POST['join_group'])) {

try {
    $join_group = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO groups_members (group_id, username)
                                VALUES (:group_id, :username)
                               ");
    $join_group->bindParam(":username", $_SESSION['username']);
    $join_group->bindParam(":group_id", $group_id);
    $join_group->execute();

    $update_members_number = $db->prepare("UPDATE groups 
                                           SET group_size = group_size + 1 
                                           WHERE id = :group_id
                                           ");
    $update_members_number->bindParam("group_id", $group_id);
    $update_members_number->execute();
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You have two buttons for two groups and you want the user to join on these two groups at same time ?

Comment: No, simply join ONE of them :)

Answer (score 0):

The most problematic issue with your code is that where you bind the group_id parameter to the query, you are not using the `$_POST` array but probably you are setting it to null. Try this:`$join_group->bindParam(":group_id", $_POST['group_id']);` instead of this `$join_group->bindParam(":group_id", $group_id);`.

Apart from this, I personally like to set the form attributes explicitly, for instance:

```
<form method='post' action='.'>
```

... and ...

```
<button type='submit' name='join_group' class='btn btn-green'>Join Group</button>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not getting the group_id value from _POST, but rather from the database, which is why i assigned it to a variable - is there any other solution to my issue?

Comment: When inserting the data into the group_members table of the database, you have to know 2 things (assuming that table defines a many-to-many relationship): the username (who is about to sign up for a group) and the group_id (which group they about to sign up for). If that's the case, you cannot get the group_id from the database at time of insertion. In other words, you get the group_id from the database when you build the form with the `foreach` loop so each button has a corresponding group_id. But you need to look for `$_POST['group_id']` at time of insertion to find which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the variable that came from your post, same as you use the `$_POST['join_group']` as the button. Try like this:

The change you need to do is just:

this line:

```
$join_group->bindParam(":group_id", $group_id);
```

To

```
$join_group->bindParam(":group_id", $_POST['group_id']);
```

And this line:

```
$update_members_number->bindParam("group_id", $group_id);
```

To

```
$update_members_number->bindParam("group_id", $_POST['group_id']);
```

That is because the `group_id` came from your HTML form through the post method, so you have to get it through the `$_POST` array from php.